# Build regular expression from language

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I have the following language: L = {w $\in$ {a,b}* | aa is not part of w}. I have to construct a regular grammar from this language and I thought about first finding the regular expression from the language. I am not sure if my solution is a good one, so I thought about asking here.

The regular expression I found is: (b*abb*)*. Is this a good one?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Almost. You should have $a \in L$, but your expression does not allow for it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't notice that. Well, if I let go of the b, aa will be part of my language, which it isn't alowed to be. I guess this "(b*abb*)* | a" solves the problem, isn't it? EDIT: in fact, b should be part of my language too. And b* also. So the answer should be (b*abb*)* | a | b*. Am I right?

Comment: Even closer. What about $ba \in L$?

Comment: Hmmm... just add (b*ba)*? Because I need bbbababa too, for example.

Comment: I think that would be enough. However, you could also simplify your expression. For example $(b^*a(b^*ba)^*|\varepsilon)b^*$ would take care of it all.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated. Only one more question. How do you come up with the simplified expression? Only by practice, or there is another way too?

Comment: There is a reason why the regular languages are called regular, that is, they have this repeating component (you could think of finite automata states, or even better elements of the [syntactic monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_monoid)). When the language is simple (like yours), then the repeating componet is easy to spot. In more complex cases experience is helpful, but sometimes not even that is enough (regular expressions can be messy). **Cont.**

Comment: **Cont.** Of couse, there are also [algorithms](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions), but I don't think you will need them unless you are dealing with some general approach. Does this answer your question? **Fin.**

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While looking for a regular expression for $L$ is a valid approach, since you ultimately want a regular grammar for $L$ an easier way in this case is to first construct a FA for the language (simple enough–one can do it with two states, both final) and use the FA to construct the grammar (even simpler–two variables and five productions).

Comment: You're right... it is easier this way. Thank you for your hint.